client-credentials is unsupported_grant_type
I am creating FastApi + KeyCloak application. Created realm, client and user
Client configuration

My user configuration

I can obtain token with help of this request

But for grant_type client-credentials I have an error:
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "Unsupported grant_type"
}

What is the difference between "password" and "client-credentials"? And how to support client-credentials?

You need to use correct "client_credentials" (not "client-credentials") Grant Type.
Required setting

Result

Difference client_credentials and password
Difference between grant_type=client_credentials and grant_type=password in Authentication Flow?
